# Change format of unmanaged image byte array

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have this code (C#):

```
    unsafe private Bitmap Test()
    {
        Bitmap test = null;
        byte[] data = memRenderAll.CurrentData;
        fixed (byte* m_pBuffer = _data)
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                Bitmap a = new Bitmap(720, 576, 2160, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(m_pBuffer));
                a.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                test =(Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);
                a.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return _test;
    }
```

By saving the stream as this:

```
 a.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I get a 10:1 reduction is size.

Is there a way of avoiding this:

```
 a.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

and specifying it somewhere/somehow in:

```
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(720, 576, 2160, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(m_pBuffer));
```

as I would like to create the Bitmap only once.

thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Don't use underscores (or `m_`) to prefix local variable names. It serves no purpose and makes the code noisier. It's also confusing since such prefixes traditionally denote private class fields.

Comment: That is the standard this company uses unfortunately. But I do agree with u. I will amend it accordingly (been working too long on this contract I am afraid) :).

Comment: @MarceloCantos Hi, I am actually going to give you a thumbs up for your comment it shook me out of a bad habit - thanks

Comment: That's a coding standard? Ouch! You're welcome, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its impossible todo in one code line using standard System.Drawing.

You use that constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx
Your code:

```
new Bitmap(720, 576, 2160, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(m_pBuffer));
```

What does it mean? Bitmap read memory pointed by m_pBuffer using fixed width, height, stride and pixel format. You can't read it as jpeg, because jpeg - image zipping fomat. Look on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_codec_example . Jpeg codec need all your image for ziping, it can't zip parts and join them after.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for replying.  Yes looking at this logically like you have (and I did not :) ) I would now agree with you. Thanks for the info and link. All v. much appreciated.